# Improve response time when database is on a dedicated server

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

**Overview**

I have a Laravel 9 application which is hosted with Digital Ocean. I use Laravel Forge to handle provisioning of the servers, management, etc. I've created two separate servers for my production environment. One to host my Laravel application code and another for the database which runs MySQL 8. These two servers are networked together and communicate over their VPC assigned private IP addresses.

**Problem**

I initially provisioned one server to host my application. This single server hosted both the Laravel application code and database. I have an endpoint that I hit to measure the response time for my application.

- With one server that hosts the codebase and database the average response time was: **~70ms**
- When I hit the same endpoint again but with my two dedicated servers the average response time was: **~135ms**

Other endpoints in my application also have a significant increase in response time when the database lives on a dedicated server vs a single server that houses everything.

**Things I have done**

- All database queries have been optimized. (n+1, etc.)
- Both networked servers are in the same region.
- Both networked server's resources (CPU, RAM) are low and are not capping out.'
- I've turned on Laravel's database config "sticky" option with no noticeable improvements.
- I've enabled PHP OPcache for PHP 8.1.

**Questions**

- How can I achieve a faster response time when my database is on a separate server than my codebase?
- Am I sacrificing performance for scalability with dedicated servers?

**TLDR**

I'm experiencing slower response times in my Laravel application when the codebase and database run on separate dedicated servers vs hosting everything on one server.

Comment: you didn't mention that you create indexes for your tables? did you. you may just forgot to mentioned it

Comment: Yes, all appropriate table indexes are in place.

Comment: How about the DB server load average? and Is your DB connection pool in manageable level? Two dedicated servers mean, are you using 2 application servers with one DB? if yes, then this could be your load balancer, proxy issue. (You mentioned that you do not have any issue with your network right)

Comment: otherwise these kind of things can happen due to bad routing/ VPN, bandwidth as you setup servers separately.

Comment: My application is behind HTTP basic auth at the moment which only I have access too so any traffic flowing into my application would only be coming from me. There are two servers total (one for the codebase and another for the database). No load balancer is in place.

Comment: in that case, my first focus is to the network, bandwidth, routing. Anyway we cannot expect the same performance from your this scenario with all in one box solution. Tyr to check the network latency first. if that thing is fine, then we have to go for other areas. You mentioned that every thing in  same region, but that not mean same location. So it is better to take the cloud team support to check the network performance. Anyway please share your experience with us.

Comment: Yes, measure the latency between the servers. I'd use `ping` for latency test, and either netcat or netperf for throughput test. There are many howto blogs, for example: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/networking/using-netperf-and-ping-to-measure-network-latency

Comment: There's always going to be more than zero overhead for using a network, but 65ms seems more like what I have experienced with inter-region latency. It's too high for latency between two servers on the same local network, so something else must be going on. I've seen bad routing configuration that passes traffic outside the VPC and back in again. Or underprovisioned bandwidth creating a bottleneck. Or undersized database server that is struggling with the query load.

Comment: Where is the server located, relative to the clients?  In network terms, the earth is more than 200 milliseconds across.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing hundreds of queries, and/or many of them are running slow.  Turn on the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to discover the naughty queries.

Comment: Additional information request - from your Laravel and your database server, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Are your servers in the same data center and on the same VLAN?
Are you sure that you are connecting with your private VLAN IP address?
Some latency is expected if you need to connect to a database on another server. Have you tried to ping between the servers to see what the latency is?

Do you really need to have the web server and the database on separate servers? If so, I would probably try Digital Oceans managed database. I have used that for several projects and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

**Q**: How can I achieve a faster response time when my database is on a separate server than my codebase?

**A**: If hosted in the same data center, the connection latency should be 30ms or less. Tested between AWS RDS and EC2 instances. Your mileage could vary depending on host.

**Q**: Am I sacrificing performance for scalability with dedicated servers?

**A**: It's standard practice to host databases separately to your application. It would be unrealistic to do otherwise for bigger projects. You can soften the impact by selectively caching data that doesn't change regularly on the main server. Unfortunately, PHP is not particularly good at this kind of fine tuning so you might be out of luck.

I can tell you that I currently run a central MySQL RDS instance that many ubuntu EC2 instances communicate with. While the queries take around 30ms, smart use of caching gives the majority of my web requests a 30ms response time in their own right. I do have the advantage of using NodeJS which is always doing things in the background without needing a request before performing work.

You may unfortunately find that you're running into one of the limitations of PHP.